# programmatically style specific types of controls

Tags: css, asp.net

I want to programmatically change a css attribute (say background colour) of specific types of controls across an ASP.net site.

Themes and skins seem to be for specific style sets and not dynamically alterable?

Was wondering if anyone has a method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a script reference to your master page and inside that script file do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('label').css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```

Assuming you want to change bg for all labels in your site.

Comment: this looks good - can i apply this to all <h1> tags for example?

Comment: Sure thing. Just put $('h1') in there instead of $('label'). I have to say though I can't see any reason why would you do this in code and not in stylesheet.

Comment: The reason for doing it code based is that the users are able to select a colour scheme which is stored in the database - which really is just a few sets of colours for various control types.  i can't style sheet n many combinations